# Remove non digits and put it in a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I want to remove the non digits in data and put it in a python list, but when I try to execute the loop it raises  "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

why ? its iterating along the b variable that have the same length that the data has.

```
data = ['1A', '1B', '2', '3A', '3B']
b=range(len(data))
pt=[]    
for x, i in zip((data), b):
    pt[i]=(''.join(c for c in x if c in digits))
```

Comment: `pt` is an empty list. You cannot do `pt[i] =...` unless that index exist in the list already. You probally want to use `pt.append(...)`.

Comment: When you say "remove non digits", Should '1A' become '1', or should it be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
 pt[i]=(''.join(c for c in x if c in digits))
```

use

```
pt.append((''.join(c for c in x if c in digits)))
```

The reason the first does not work because `pt[i]` requires that there exists `i`-th element of the list `pt`.

Actually, you can rewrite your code to be much simpler:

```
pt=[]    
for x in data:
    pt.append((''.join(c for c in x if c in digits)))
```

or even simpler using *list comprehension*:

```
pt = [(''.join(c for c in x if c in digits)) for x in data]
```

Comment: You could go one step further and use ```str.isdigit()``` instead of creating the digit list and comparing.

Answer (score 0):

that happens because you're trying to assign values to non-existing items in pt, because you can't just put e.g pt[1] = 3 without pt[1] existing already.

- so just change it by either :

  `pt=data` instead of `pt = []`

  or use

  `pt.append((''.join(c for c in x if c in digits)))`

> this one doesn't require a list of digits

```
    data = ['1A', '1B', '2', '3A', '3B']
    pt=[]
    for i, x in enumerate(data):
        pt.append((''.join(c for c in x if c.isdigit())))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
digits ="0123456789"
data = ['1A', '1B', '2', '3A', '3B']
pt=[]
for i, x in enumerate(data):
    pt.append((''.join(c for c in x if c in digits)))
print(pt)
```

Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use list comprehension

```
data = ['1A', '1B', '2', '3A', '3B']
pt = [x for x in data if x in digits]
```

Comment: This will not work as intended. Indexes with a mixture of digits and non-digits will not get added to the list. The digit needs to be extracted.

Comment: If he wants to get '1' from '1A' yes, you're right. I was assuming he wanted strings with only digits.